Template argument deduction in perfect forwarding
I'm learning perfect forwarding, and run the example code(listed bellow)
template<typename T>
void show_type(T t){
    std::cout << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void perfect_forwarding(T &&t){
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "is std::string: " << std::is_same<std::string, T>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "is lval-reference: " << std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "is rval-reference: " << std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value << std::endl;
    show_type(static_cast<T&&>(t));
}

std::string get_string(){
  return "hi world";
}

int main() {
  std::string s = "hello world";
  perfect_forwarding(s);              //call 1
  perfect_forwarding(get_string());   //call 2
}

The output is
is std::string: false
is lval-reference: true
is rval-reference: false
Ss
is std::string: true
is lval-reference: false
is rval-reference: false
Ss

And I debug with gdb, find out the two calls to perfect_forwarding()
are instantiated as
perfect_forwarding<std::string&>(std::string&) //for call 1
perfect_forwarding<std::string>(std::string&&) //for call 2

My question is
In call 1, why T was deducted as std::string&, I thought it would be std::string, and T&& should be deducted as std::string&&
In call 2, I thought T should be deducted as std::string&&
I can't find an article talk about this

Continuing from our discussion at staging ground: Why would T&& be deduced to anything else than std::string& in call 1? Anything else would cause perfect forwarding to not work. If T&& would be deduced to std::string&& instead, then the reference could not bind the lvalue argument. So the rules are specified this way in order for perfect forwarding to work. For call 2 it would have been possible to specify deduction of T to std::string&& as well, but the outcome for perfect forwarding would be the same.

If your question is what exactly the deduction rules are here: The general rule is that template parameters are never deduced to reference types. For forwarding references, i.e. function parameters of the form T&& where T is a template parameter of the function, there is however a specific exception stating that T will be deduced to a lvalue reference type if the argument given to the function is a lvalue. Without that exception perfect forwarding wouldn't work.

@user17732522 understood, thank you. But for call 2, why std::string is equivalent to std::string&&

When you pass an argument to a function which has a forwarding reference T&& as a parameter for that argument, one of two things happen:

If the argument is an lvalue (such as s), T deduces to an lvalue reference (such as std::string&).
There are no references to references, so you get reference collapsing.
For instance, T&& where T = std::string& appears to be an rvalue reference to an lvalue reference, and this collapses to just std::string&.

Otherwise, if the argument is an rvalue (such as get_string()), T deduces to the type of the expression (std::string), so T&& is simply std::string&&.


See also template deduction rules for a more detailed explanation.
Note that in your GDB inspection of
perfect_forwarding<std::string&>(std::string&)
perfect_forwarding<std::string>(std::string&&)

... what appears between pointy brackets is what T deduced to,
and what appears between parentheses is what T&& collapsed to.
